# How to enforce single direction uniqueness in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, one-to-many

Suppose I have a `job_assignment` table that contains `worker_id` and `job_id` from the `worker` and `job` tables.

A worker can have many jobs but a job can be assigned to only one worker. Is there a way to ensure this in postgres?

If I put `UNIQUE(worker_id, job_id)`, this will only be a one to one mapping. I have read up on `UNIQUE FOREIGN KEY` but I am still not sure if it is the right way to do this.

Comment: The easiest way to do that is to get rid of `job_assignment` and just store a `worker_id` in `job`.

Answer (score 1):

This should not be modeled with an intermediate `job_assignment` table — that would be the correct way to model a many-to-many relationship.

Instead you should add a foreign key column `worker_id` to `job`. That way it is guaranteed that a job can only belong to one worker.

If there are fields you want to store in a `job_assignment`, you could instead add a `job_assignment_id` foreign key to `job` and a `worker_id` foreign key to `job_assignment`. But I'd say that you might as well add these data to `job`. It's fine to create a data model that reflects reality, but your model should also allow your SQL queries to be simple, with no more joins than necessary.

Comment: The reason I created this intermediate table is because there are other job_asssignment specific data, and to me this assignment data seems to be more of the job_assignment property than the job property. Is it still bad if this is the case?

Comment: I tried to address that comment in the extended answer.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use an intermediate table for this, but you can do what you asked for by adding a `UNIQUE(job_id)` constraint to `job_assignment`.

This ensures every `job` is listed at most once in `job_assignment`, thus assigned to at most one worker.